# Multiple email accounts to trigger?

Tags: if-this-then-that

I have several email accounts that I want to send to `trigger@recipe.ifttt.com`, however it appears that IFTTT only supports a single email per account.

Is there a way to facilitate many emails going into a single trigger vs setting up so many IFTTT accounts?